# LINQ query AND & OR

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I'm starting my journey with .NET and I need a little help.

I will describe my situation by example what I have and what I need to do but I don't know how to do that.

So I have a class like this

```
public class Ban
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nick { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

and variable *bans* which is *IQueryable*

Then in method of signature

```
public IEnumerable<Ban> FindBans(Ban filter);
```

I need to search through that *bans* variable;

**How I search now**

```
public IEnumerable<Ban> FindBans(Ban filter)
{
    var bans = GetBansQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.GroupName))
    {
        bans = bans.Where(b => b.GroupName == filter.GroupName);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Nick))
    {
        bans = bans.Where(b => b.Nick == filter.Nick);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.IP))
    {
        bans = bans.Where(b => b.IP == filter.IP);
    }

    return bans.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Which filters with AND. SQL query part will be like this

```
... WHERE group_name = 'abc' AND nick = 'def' AND ip = 'ghi';
```

**What I need is**

```
... WHERE group_name = 'abc' AND (nick = 'def' OR ip = 'ghi');
```

All of this need to be dynamic (if we don't pass GroupName don't filter by it etc.)
I have no idea how I can achieve that beside making this dynamics manualy like

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.GroupName) && 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Nick) && 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.IP))
{
    bans = bans.Where(b => b.GroupName == filter.GroupName);
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.GroupName) && 
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Nick) && 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.IP))
{
    bans = bans.Where(b => b.GroupName == filter.GroupName && b.Nick == filter.Nick);
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.GroupName) && 
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Nick) && 
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.IP))
{
    bans = bans.Where(b => b.GroupName == filter.GroupName && (b.Nick == filter.Nick || b.IP == filter.IP));
}
```

and so on... and now add another variable to Ban.

Comment: Try this : `.Where((b => b.GroupName =="abc") && b.(nick =="def")||b.ip=="ghi")`

Comment: @Thirisangu: That doesn't handle the null cases, like in the current code. I think the SQL statement is not entirely correct.

Comment: I think PredicateBuilder can help you. http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify you entire constraint like this:

```
bans = bans.Where(b => ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.GroupName) || b.GroupName == filter.GroupName )
                        &&
                        ( ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Nick) || b.Nick == filter.Nick )
                          ||
                          ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.IP) || b.IP == filter.IP )
                        )
                 );
```

Comment: If GroupName is empty, Nick is empty and IP is "1.1.1.1" the part with checking IP won't even get evaluated. I think, because it's not working.

Comment: @user2825007: Are you sure. LINQ `Where` is evaluated when it enumerates the items, right.

Comment: Yes. http://i.imgur.com/qzKbkXn.png The first (Name in this case) is empty so it evaluate it to true so it ignore the rest of the OR statement.

Comment: @user2825007: That is the general concept behind an `or`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You probably would like to look at [Scott Hansleman](http://www.hanselman.com/) blog post on dynamic sql, predicate builder and linqkit:

[The Weekly Source Code 48 - DynamicQueryable makes custom LINQ expressions easier](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/theweeklysourcecode48dynamicqueryablemakescustomlinqexpressionseasier.aspx)

Otherwise there is a very nice blog post about using dynamic filter with Kendo UI grid and Web Api:

[Kendo UI Open Sources Dynamic LINQ Helpers](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/14-01-02/kendo-ui-open-sources-dynamic-linq-helpers)

Answer (score 1):

You could special-case the situation where both nick and ip are known:

```
public IEnumerable<Ban> FindBans(Ban filter)
{
    var bans = GetBansQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.GroupName))
    {
        bans = bans.Where(b => b.GroupName == filter.GroupName);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Nick) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.IP))
    {
        bans = bans.Where(b => b.Nick == filter.Nick || b.IP == filter.IP);
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Nick))
    {
        // filter.IP is empty
        bans = bans.Where(b => b.Nick == filter.Nick);
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.IP))
    {
        // filter.Nick is empty
        bans = bans.Where(b => b.IP == filter.IP);
    }

    return bans.AsEnumerable();
}
```